# Plotly Stacked Bar Chart Annotations

Tags: python, annotations, bar-chart, plotly, stacked-chart

I've been trying to create annotations for stacked plotly bar charts, based on the tutorial example - [Styled Bar Chart with Direct Labels](https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/)

I modified the example, as below:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

x1 = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
y1 = [20, 14, 23]

x2 = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
y2 = [40, 10, 55]

bar1 = go.Bar(
        x=x1,y=y1,
        marker=dict(
            color='rgb(158,202,225)'
        ),
        opacity=0.6,
        name = 'Type 1'
    )

bar2 = go.Bar(
        x=x2,y=y2,
        marker=dict(
            color='rgb(158,202,0)'
        ),
        opacity=0.6,
        name = 'Type 2'
    )

data = [bar1, bar2]

annotation1 = [dict(x=xi,y=yi,
         text=str(yi),
         xanchor='center',
         yanchor='bottom',
         showarrow=False,
    ) for xi, yi in zip(x1, y1)]

annotation2 = [dict(x=xi,y=yi,
         text=str(yi),
         xanchor='center',
         yanchor='bottom',
         showarrow=False,
    ) for xi, yi in zip(x2, y2)]

layout = go.Layout(annotations=annotation1 + annotation2, barmode="stack")

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
url5 = py.plot(fig, filename = 'bar-direct-labels', sharing = 'secret', fileopt = 'overwrite')
```

Which created this plot: https://plot.ly/~Viola.Rudenko/918/type-1-vs-type-2/

[image]

How can I align the annotation text with the correct product type, so the text appears in the middle of the corresponding product type bar chart? I tried to shift `y` in `annotation2` by `y1` `(y = yi+y1)`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Which version of plotly is this using? Things changed around 4.0.

Comment: @JDL I'm using plotly 1.12.9 (I just upgraded to it).

Comment: hmm, the version numbers must be different for the R and python interfaces. I'm an R user; I'll let someone with python knowledge answer this one.

Comment: Thanks @JDL! I use R too. How did you solve this in R?

Comment: The short answer is, with the new version I haven't! plotly have completely changed their API, and have made me a lot of work...

Comment: Thanks @JDL! I guess it's a good question to ask them when I'm at Plotcon next week.